# Mouse coordinates outside of a form

Tags: vb.net, mouse-coordinates

I'm trying to make a simple mouse macro program but i cannot figure out how to get the coordinates of the mouse outside of the form itself.
I have tried with `MousePosition` and `Cursor.Position` but this only seems to take the coordinates inside the form.

I have looked around on the internet but most examples are to capture inside the form/application and the only similar question i found on StackOverflow was unanswered.
[VB.net -- Getting mouse coordinates outside the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359251/vb-net-getting-mouse-coordinates-outside-the-form)

So, is the a simple way to capture the mouse coordinates outside of its own program?
If not a simple way, could someone explain the complicated way a bit?
I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming WinForms, you can try using just a timer:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  Me.Text = MousePosition.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: This works indeed for tracing the coordinates, but i am also trying to add the coordinates to a list when i click, so that can be later to replay the actions. But when i click outside of the form, the click does not register because the form is not focused anymore, the event is ofcourse the form_mouseclick event, is there any event in VB that will work when clicking outside of the form or will i need to create my own event for it? or is there another way i can obtain this result?

Comment: @Vahx You can replace `MousePosition` in my code with `MouseButtons`, which would tell you which mouse button is pressed at the time of the tick event.

Comment: thx but its more of where the button was clicked instead of which button.

Comment: @Vahx Sorry, I misunderstood your comment.  You are basically talking about a global hook, not events from your form.  See [Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)

Comment: ok thankx, looks a bit complicated but i found some VB variants on the net so i think i'll figure it out. :) answer accepted

Comment: This gave me the results I needed, however rather then set up a timer I just used system.threading.thread.sleep(2000) followed by Me.Text = MousePosition.ToString